# Apache slows down and suspicious entries in error.log

Tags: server, apache2

I run Apache2 on headless Ubuntu 18.04 server, an Intel based Chinese Beelink NUC clone type of device. I run a few web apps such as Emby, PiHole, Medusa and Syncthing and two Wordpress sites, very low traffic, basically just for my own use. The web apps are accessed with reverse proxy setups to minimise open ports.

It was working well until recently, now it slows to a crawl after a day or two. Restarting Apache or php7.3-fms fixes it for a while.

In the error.log are several suspicious entries:

```
[Sun Feb 16 11:43:19.629053 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 27751] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 62.210.220.48:10617] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 69771.xc.k9sp3u.cn:80
[Sun Feb 16 11:43:19.629148 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 27751] [client 62.210.220.48:10617] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by http:/69771.xc.k9sp3u.cn

[Sun Feb 16 12:23:25.498002 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 21676] [client 195.154.102.22:44378] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 74105.zc.schoolsafty.top
[Sun Feb 16 12:23:25.738934 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 21726] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 115.231.220.79:3803 (*) failed

[Sun Feb 16 12:25:00.568318 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 21558] [client 163.172.12.108:44502] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: www.3gmir3.com
[Sun Feb 16 12:25:00.568342 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 20800] [client 62.210.220.48:41022] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: www.cq3.in
```

These are a few snippets, there is lot more similar entries.

Any ideas what's going on? I've no idea why these URL are in my logs.

John

Edit - Thanks Florian for tidying the logs.

Comment: Can you include the relevant configuration? It seems you've configured it as an open proxy, which is probably not an good idea...

Comment: I have several virtual hosts, here's one example: ProxyPass /syncthing/ http://192.168.1.2:8384/
<Location /syncthing/>
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.2:8384/
    Require all granted
</Location>

Comment: Sorry haven't quite mastered the formatting here but I hope the above is clear.